kivy buildzeor stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
I want to use OpenCV and Kivy to create an APK, with the function of taking photos and applying the Canny edge detection algorithm to the images. The code is as follows:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
from android.storage import app_storage_path
import time
import cv2

request_permissions([
    Permission.CAMERA,
    Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
])

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        index: 0
        id: camera
        resolution: (1920,1080)
        play: True
        allow_stretch: True
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: -90
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()

<DisplayImagePopup>:
    image_source: ''
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            source: root.image_source
        Button:
            text: 'Process Image'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_press: root.process_image()
''')

class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        storage_path = app_storage_path()  # Get the safe storage path for the app
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        filename = "{}/IMG_{}.png".format(storage_path, timestr)
        camera.export_to_png(filename)
        self.show_image(filename)

    def show_image(self, filename):
        popup = DisplayImagePopup(title='Captured Image', image_source=filename)
        popup.open()

class DisplayImagePopup(Popup):
    image_source = StringProperty('')

    def process_image(self):
        image = cv2.imread(self.image_source)
        imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgBlur = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgGray, 10, 10, 10)
        imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (5, 5), 1)
        adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                                cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 3)
        imgCanny = cv2.Canny(adaptive_thresh, 100, 150)
        processed_filename = self.image_source.replace('.png', '_processed.png')
        cv2.imwrite(processed_filename, imgCanny)
        self.image_source = processed_filename  # Update the image displayed in the popup

class TestCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestCamera().run()


The code itself seems fine, but after modifying it to implement Canny edge detection, when clicking on the image, a red dot appears on the image. The code is as follows:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
import cv2
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
from android.storage import app_storage_path
import time

request_permissions([
    Permission.CAMERA,
    Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
])

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        index: 0
        id: camera
        resolution: (1920,1080)
        play: True
        allow_stretch: True
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: -90
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()

<DisplayImagePopup>:
    image_source: ''
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        InteractiveImage:
            source: root.image_source
            on_touch_down: root.on_image_touch(*args)
        Button:
            text: 'Process Image'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_press: root.process_image()
''')

class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        storage_path = app_storage_path()
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        filename = "{}/IMG_{}.png".format(storage_path, timestr)
        camera.export_to_png(filename)
        self.show_image(filename)

    def show_image(self, filename):
        popup = DisplayImagePopup(title='Captured Image', image_source=filename)
        popup.open()

class InteractiveImage(Image):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            with self.canvas:
                Color(1, 0, 0)
                d = 10  # diameter of the ellipse
                Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            return True
        return super(InteractiveImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class DisplayImagePopup(Popup):
    image_source = StringProperty('')

    def process_image(self):
        image = cv2.imread(self.image_source)
        imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgBlur = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgGray, 10, 10, 10)
        imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (5, 5), 1)
        adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                                cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 3)
        imgCanny = cv2.Canny(adaptive_thresh, 100, 150)
        processed_filename = self.image_source.replace('.png', '_processed.png')
        cv2.imwrite(processed_filename, imgCanny)
        self.image_source = processed_filename  # Update the image displayed in the popup

class TestCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestCamera().run()


At this point, the following error occurs, and even when reverting back to the original code, the same error persists. It is necessary to rebuild using 'buildozer android clean' in order for the original code to run properly.
HWCDY:/ $ run-as org.test.myapt
HWCDY:/data/data/org.test.myapt $ cd files/app/.kivy/logs/
HWCDY:/data/data/org.test.myapt/files/app/.kivy/logs $ ls
kivy_24-04-22_0.txt
HWCDY:/data/data/org.test.myapt/files/app/.kivy/logs $ cat kivy_24-04-22_0.txt
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapt/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-04-22_0.txt
[DEBUG  ] Config: Upgrading from 0 to 1
[WARNING] Config: Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING] Config: Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 27)
[INFO   ] Kivy: v2.2.0
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapt/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.10.10 (main, Apr 21 2024, 22:32:18) [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at ""
[INFO   ] Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] Factory: 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/wuqx1999/packing/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Why is that, thank you very much
I don't understand why .I want the second copy of the code to work as well.
I found someone on GitHub with the same issue, but unfortunately, there are no answers either.https://github.com/liyuanrui/kivy-for-android-opencv-demo/issues/4

Sorry if that's a stupid question, but are you sure you installed this module with pip install opencv-python?

I'm sure, otherwise the first code wouldn't have worked

install opencv and opencv-python and opencv-contrib

I indeed hadn't installed opencv-contrib before, but even after installing it now, it still doesn't work, and I'm still encountering the aforementioned error. Currently, the only solution is to use 'buildozer android clean'.

Please attach the buildozer spec file you are using the only something cam be said, generally speaking it is always the requirements specification error in buildozer spec
